# autoincrement number in textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

How to autoincrement the value in textBox1(which is the ID) everytime I click the save button? My problem is that the value in the textBox1 only increments everytime I run the winform.

For example, I run the winform and the last value that the ID has was 2, the textbox1 will generate number 3 and after I click the save button it doesn't generate the next number instead it will only increment if I close the form and rerun it again. plsss help..

In form load

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a;
        String path1 = "Data Source=LOCALHOST; Initial Catalog= ss; username=root; password=''";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(path1);
        con.Open();
        string query = "Select Max(ID) from inc";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            string val = dr[0].ToString();
            if (val == "")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "1";
            }
            else
            {
                a = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
                a = a + 1;
                textBox1.Text = a.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

In save button

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String path = "Data Source=LOCALHOST; Initial Catalog= ss; username=root; password=''";
        MySqlConnection sqlconn = new MySqlConnection(path); //communicator //constructors
        MySqlCommand sqlcomm = new MySqlCommand();
        MySqlDataReader sqldr;
        sqlconn.Open();
        sqlcomm.Connection = sqlconn;
        sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlcomm.CommandText = "Select * from inc where ID=" + textBox1.Text + "";

        sqldr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
        sqldr.Read();

        if (sqldr.HasRows)
        {
            textBox3.Text = sqldr[0].ToString();

        }
        sqlconn.Close();


        if (textBox1.Text == textBox3.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ID already exists!");

        }

        else
        {
            String path1 = "Data Source=LOCALHOST; Initial Catalog= ss; username=root; password=''";
            MySqlConnection sqlconnn = new MySqlConnection(path1); //communicator //constructors
            MySqlCommand sqlcommm = new MySqlCommand();
            sqlconnn.Open();
            sqlcommm.Connection = sqlconnn;
            sqlcommm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlcommm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO inc (ID,Lastname) VALUES ("+ textBox1.Text +", '" + textBox2.Text + "')";
            sqlcommm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlconnn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("RECORD SAVED!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a numeric updown instead.

Answer (score 0):

What only you need is update textBox1.Text after saving record

```
...
sqlcommm.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlconnn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("RECORD SAVED!");
//Update textBox1.Text
....
```

You have to generate next value for next saving!

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a;
        String path1 = "Data Source=LOCALHOST; Initial Catalog= ss; username=root; password=''";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(path1);
        con.Open();
        string query = "Select Max(ID) from inc";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            string val = dr[0].ToString();
           setText(val );
        }
}


   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String path = "Data Source=LOCALHOST; Initial Catalog= ss; username=root; password=''";
        MySqlConnection sqlconn = new MySqlConnection(path); //communicator //constructors
        MySqlCommand sqlcomm = new MySqlCommand();
        MySqlDataReader sqldr;
        sqlconn.Open();
        sqlcomm.Connection = sqlconn;
        sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlcomm.CommandText = "Select * from inc where ID=" + textBox1.Text + "";

        sqldr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
        sqldr.Read();

        if (sqldr.HasRows)
        {
            textBox3.Text = sqldr[0].ToString();

        }
        sqlconn.Close();


        if (textBox1.Text == textBox3.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ID already exists!");

        }

        else
        {
            String path1 = "Data Source=LOCALHOST; Initial Catalog= ss; username=root; password=''";
            MySqlConnection sqlconnn = new MySqlConnection(path1); //communicator //constructors
            MySqlCommand sqlcommm = new MySqlCommand();
            sqlconnn.Open();
            sqlcommm.Connection = sqlconnn;
            sqlcommm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlcommm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO inc (ID,Lastname) VALUES ("+ textBox1.Text +", '" + textBox2.Text + "')";
            sqlcommm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlconnn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("RECORD SAVED!");
           setText( textBox1.Text);
        }
    }

 private void setText(string newValue)
{

            if (newValue == "")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "1";
            }
            else
            {
                a = Convert.ToInt32(newValue);
                a = a + 1;
                textBox1.Text = a.ToString();
            }
}
```

You need to update ID on each successful save.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
ViewState["hereYourThingToIncrement"] = "1";
yourtxt.Text = ViewState["hereYourThingToIncrement"].ToString();
}
```

and then

```
protected void button(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
int number=Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["hereYourThingToIncrement"]);
        ViewState["hereYourThingToIncrement"] = number+ 1;
        yourtxt.Text = ViewState["hereYourThingToIncrement"].ToString();

}
```

Comment: we are in winforms world

Comment: his question is about winforms not webforms :)

Comment: Okay, I was thinking that was in a webform